# Element not interactable when sending keys, even after a successful click

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to send keys to username and password so I can log in in the following website (yes, mobile version):

https://m.bancosecurity.cl/

I always get the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)
```

My code is:

```
Username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="UserName"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Username)
Username.send_keys("xx.xxx.xxx-x")
```

The code that produces the error is:

```
Username.send_keys("xx.xxx.xxx-x")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there are multiple input on the page So tried to access it with the help element indexes

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "((//input[@id='UserName'])[2])")))
username.send_keys("Username")

password= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "((//input[@id='Password'])[2])")))
password.send_keys("passowrd")
```

So above I have just checked the presence of the element with `excplicitWait` and send_keys to the input

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 elements matching `//*[@id="UserName"]` XPath selector on that page.  The first is not the filed receiving user input with `send_keys`.
So clicking on it, especially clicking with JavaScript on it just does nothing while sending a string input to it with Selenium `send_keys` is not allowed.
You should do 2 things to make your code working here:

1. Set explicit wait to make the page loaded before accessing the element.
2. To use correct locator.
   Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel' and contains(@style,'block')]//*[@id='UserName']")))
username.click()
username.send_keys("xx.xxx.xxx-x")
```